# Comparison of hex numbers (32'h and 0x) in tcl script

Tags: tcl

I am writing a tcl script (in questasim) which does the following comparison. But the values are same but still not matching. any pointer to this would be helpful.

## Code Snippet:

```
set ExpAddr 0xffff0000
set Addr "sim:/tb_top/dut_top/m1/m2/m3/addr"
set ActualAddr "[examine -hex $Addr]"

if { $ActualAddr == $ExpAddr } {
    puts  " ADDR MATCH DETECTED @ time [expr $now/1000000.0] us "
} else {
    puts  " ADDR MATCH NOT DETECTED @ time [expr $now/1000000.0] us " 
    puts $ActualAddr
    puts $ExpAddr
}
```

## Result:

```
ADDR MATCH NOT DETECTED @ time 145.99 us
Actual Address   : 44'h000ffff0000
Expected Address : 0xffff0000
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode that address. This is a job for `scan`, one of the mild-mannered superheroes of Tcl!

```
scan [examine -hex $Addr] "%d'h%x" BitWidth ActualAddr
```

Now you should be able to compare with 0xffff0000 using numeric comparison (`==`). As a bonus, you've also got the number of real bits in the value (stored in the `BitWidth` variable).

Comment: Thanks Donal. It works now! I tried Yann's solution too! both of them works.

Comment: Hi Donal, The same comparison is not working with the "when" command. for example, `when -label my_addr "$actualaddr == $expaddr" { ... }`  the actual address is in 44'h format and expaddr is in 0x format. Do u have any idea on this ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
set hex 0xffff0000
```

to set as hexadecimal value

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, based on the `examine` command and `sim:/` path, that this resembles a script for ModelSim. That being the case, `44'h` marks a 44-bit hexadecimal value in Verilog fashion.

Possibly the easiest way to get the numeric comparison is to request a different radix out of examine. If you use `examine -radix unsigned` you should get the decimal form, and you can use `expr` to convert 0x form hexadecimal constants to numbers.

Sources: Tcl wiki [hex to decimal](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3242#pagetoc9aaa5898), ModelSim SE Reference Manual: Commands: examine.

Comment: Hi Yann, The same comparison is not working with the "when" command. for example, when -label my_addr "$actualaddr == $expaddr" { ... } the actual address is in 44'h format and expaddr is in 0x format. Do u have any idea on this ?