# Comparison of Hex Numbers in Tcl

Tags: hex, tcl

I am trying to compare the two following hex numbers in a TCL Script:

0x00001111
32'h00001111

They should be equal to each other, but I am having trouble comparing them because of the difference in formatting.

I have tried using "scan" command to convert, but have not gotten the correct output I am looking for.

Code snippet:

```
    set read1 0x00001111
    set read2 32'h00001111
    
    set new_read [scan $read2 %x]
    if ($read1 == $read2) {
        puts "Two values equal"
    }
```

This code does not work and sets new_read to 4369. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you explain the format of the second number: `32'h00001111` ?  It's not anything I recognise, except that it vaguely reminds me of an ancient format for character strings used in early versions of Fortran.

Comment: It is just a 32 bit hex number retrieved from a verilog script

Comment: Also can you confirm that these are really hexadecimal numbers - the fact that all the digits are `0` or `1` suggests that they could be binary ?

Comment: Yeah they are hex numbers...I was just using 1111 for simplicity

Comment: So I'm guessing that the `32'h` is a fixed 4-character prefix which you need to skip over, then treat the rest of the string as a hex number.

Comment: I think that would work, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change the format specifier to `scan` to sth. like:

```
 if {[scan $read2 "%d'h%x" bw new_read] == 2} {
   # on success 
 } else {
   # on failure
 }
```

This way, you will be able to compare `scan $read1 %x` and `$new_read` using `==` & friends.

Comment: This has been covered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490027/comparison-of-hex-numbers-32h-and-0x-in-tcl-script

Comment: If you knew that there is only the prefix `32'h`, you could also strip it off: `set read2 [string map {"32'h" ""} $read2]`, and then use `scan $read2 %x`.

Comment: When using `scan`, you should check its result to see if the expected number of fields (2 in this case) were parsed, as the command does not error out if it can't scan anything. Failing to check the result is a common issue... but the command is often forgotten so not that many scripts are buggy from this anyway.

Comment: I modified the snippet to document the need for a parse check.